# How to get row wise sum of all previous value in column using django queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I want to get the row wise sum of all previous value in column amount.

models.py

```
class PaymentRecord(models.Model):
    invoice_no = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, unique=False, related_name='paymentrecord', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    paid_into = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=PAID)
    payment_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    cheque_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
    cheque_no = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

I tried the queryset

```
pay_receipt = PaymentRecord.objects.filter(Q(payment_date__range=[startdate, enddate]),Q(paid_into='ONLINE') | Q(paid_into='CHEQUE')).annotate(totals=Sum('amount')).order_by('payment_date')
```

I want the result like this

```
Id   paid_into   payment_date   amount    SumAmount
---------------------------------------------------------
1     ONLINE      12-09-2019        40.00     40.00
2     ONLINE      12-09-2019        40.00     80.00
3     ONLINE      12-09-2019        45.00     125.00         
4     ONLINE      12-09-2019        50.00     175.00
```

Answer (score 2):

On Django>=2 and on a supported DB, you can use the `Window` function to get the accumuation:

```
from django.db.models import Window, Sum

PaymentRecord.objects.filter(...).annotate(
    SumAmount=Window(Sum(F('amount')), order_by=F('pk').asc())
).values('id', 'paid_into', 'payment_date', 'amount', 'SumAmount')
```

Comment: I'm using mysql 5.7 getting a syntax error near '(ORDER BY `account_paymentrecord`.`id` ASC) AS `SumAmount` FROM `account_payment'

Answer (score 0):

You probably will achieve what you want with the following:

```
from django.db.models import Window, Sum
PaymentRecord.objects.filter(...).annotate(
    SumAmount=Window(
        Sum(F('amount')),
        partition_by=F('paid_into'),
        order_by=F('payment_date').asc()
    )
).values('id', 'paid_into', 'payment_date', 'amount', 'SumAmount')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this is simply code for you hopefully it will work!

```
query = ModelName.objects.aggregate(Sum('field_name'))
context = {'query':query}
reutrn render(request,'your_template_name',context)
```

in **html file:**

```
<td>{{ query}}</td>
```

Comment: I want the result row wise.

Comment: @SachinSingh Try This it will also work for row wise

Comment: i am getting a result in form of dict. {'amount__sum': 157925.0} how can i print the table which i have mentioned above.

Comment: You can add simply context and add in your html file

Comment: can you please share a snippet how to do that.

Comment: @SachinSingh Answer Updated